# Run ServiceStack Console as Daemon on DigitalOcean

Tags: mono, servicestack, daemon, digital-ocean

All,

I have successfully installed my ServiceStack console app on my DigitalOcean droplet and can run it from the command line using mono. When I do this, my app is accessible using Postman from my laptop.

I have also tried to use Upstart to run my app as a daemon. I can see from the logging that it successfully launches when I reboot, but unless I am logged in as root and have started my console app from the command line, I can't access the console app from the outside when running as the daemon. I have tried this with ufw enabled (configured to allow the port I am using) and disabled and it makes no difference.

I am reasonably certain this is a permissions issue in my upstart config file for my console app, but since I am brand new to linux, I am unclear as to my next step to get this console app available as a daemon.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated...

Bruce

```
# ServiceStack GeoAPIConsole Application

# description “GeoAPIConsole”
# author      “Bruce Parr”

setuid root
# start on started rc
start on started networking
stop on stopping rc

respawn

exec start-stop-daemon --start --exec /usr/bin/mono /var/console/GeoAPIConsole.exe
```

Comment: If you run from console "nohup /var/console/GeoAPIConsole.exe &" is your application accessible from the outside?

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. I'll try this tonight and will post back.

Comment: I tried the nohup approach and kept getting permission denied...

Comment: Does the application run when you start it with nohup or stops? For example it can stop if you try to use ReadLine() in the code. (it will throw permisson deny exception).

Comment: It never starts. I immediately get the permission denied, even running as root. 

What is happening now is I can see the daemon started, but I still can't access the API when the daemon is executed from startup. If I am logged in and start the daemon manually from the command line, I can access the API from the outside.

Comment: You will have more luck with this question on Super User. As this question is more about configuration of Upstart and Linux than ServiceStack. I would ask it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked. I added a user geoapiconsole and added the -S and -c switches, then I followed with initctrl start GeoAPIConsole

```
# ServiceStack Example Application

description "ServiceStack Example"
author      "ServiceStack"

start on started rc
stop on stopping rc

respawn

exec start-stop-daemon -S -c geoapiconsole --exec /usr/bin/mono /var/console/GeoAPIConsole.exe
```